# my team working in asp.net shopping cart project .Is it possible to integrate First Data Alternative Payment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway

My team working in asp.net shopping cart project and we have integrated the first data payment gateway.

Our project mainly done in flash and our asp.net team taken data from flash and integrated the first data payment gateway.
Now we want to integrate First Data Alternative Payment.

Please provide any payment api for doing the same

If anybody knows about this payment gateway please help me to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just read their documentation.
http://www.firstdata.com/downloads/marketing-merchant/fd_globalgatewayinternetpaymentgatewayconnect_integrationguideemea.pdf

Section 3.2 discusses ASP integration which you can port or reuse.